# How to scroll a usercontrol popup when focused virtual keyboard

Tags: c#, windows-8, user-controls, popup, microsoft-metro

In my windows 8 application, i need to collect the user details. For that i am using user control inside a popup. In simulator, when open virtual keyboard the popup doesn't scrolling. How to scroll only popup when open virtual keyboard.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=begdh4&s=6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [Handling the virtual keyboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/09/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developers-handling-the-virtual-keyboard.aspx) should answer your question. You can use Margins, RenderTransform, Canvas.Top, or any other layout mechanism to push the popup wherever you want it.